# What is the purpose of Opera's "Retarded Image Loading" setting?

Tags: configuration-files, opera

The opera.ini file for Opera web browser has a setting called "Retarded Image Loading" under UserPrefs. I can't find an explanation for this anywhere, but I can find it in others' copy/paste on message boards. What is it for??

Comment: It's for offending people everywhere!

Comment: "Retarded" in the sense of "delayed", not in the sense of "stoooopid" :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a leftover trace of an outdated Opera feature that would postphone loading of images. It was mostly used on low-end hardware and entirely removed several years ago.

Feel free to remove that line from your opera.ini since it has no effect anymore :)